# Disproportionate stratified sampling that follows proportional trend?

Tags: sampling, stratification, research-design

I'm conducting a study across four counties to determine which of four different methods is most effective in detecting nutria. 60 sites will be randomly selected within a 5-meter buffer of any open water. I'm planning to stratify evenly between lentic and lotic, so 30 lentic sites and 30 lotic sites. Given that nutria will utilize any open water, I can't exclude certain water habitat. Therefore, my idea is to stratify waterbodies by size, which gives me 5 size categories in lentic sites and 5 categories in lotic sites.

There are 3474 total water bodies in the lentic category. I created the 5 categories using a log scale, so that 1549 water bodies are less than 100 m2, 1460 are between 100-1,000 m2, 381 between 1,000-10,000 m2,  76 between 10,000-100,000 m2, and 8 are greater than 100,000 m2.

The issue is that I only have 30 sites to allocate between these 5 categories. I would only have 1 site for the largest size category if I did a proportional stratified design. My thought is to impose a minimum number of sites in each category, that way I can still have enough sites in the largest size category to gain some inference while also reflecting the distribution of size categories. If so, how do I know what a good minimum number of sites would be? Is there a better way to sample lentic and lotic sites? Thank you in advance for your thoughts and help!